# Create future timezone for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, time, future, timezone-offset

I am creating a wordpress project/website using lots of news events and dates for the post content.

I need the overall date of the Wordpress system to be in the future. In fact 2022. So it's as if we are looking at a future website.

I wonder if I can just insert my own custom timezone in the General tab and select that instead?

Comment: Wouldn't it have taken less time to try than to post this?

Answer (score 0):

Time zones adjust the value of the clock by an offset.  The offset is usually in terms of hours or minutes.  An offset large enough to skew the date by *years* would not work.

You would instead need to intercept all calls to the system clock and modify the value returned.  Or just set your clock ahead (and disable time synchronization) if you have control of the server.